# Serenity Report not showing all the scenarios outline mentioned in feature file though taking all screenshot for all scenario outline

Tags: java, maven, automation, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

The reports contains only @test2 Scenario outline but it does not contain @test1 scenario outline.
I checked the serenity report folder and it has sceenshot for @test1 Scenario outline too. I don't know why this is happening. When I running the same test with 'Scenario' instead of 'Scenario Outline' the report is getting generated correctly.

Feature file:

```
@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"features"}, glue = {"stepdefinitons"},plugin={"pretty"})
public class serenity runner{
}
```

I have two scenario outline in feature file

```
@test1
Scenario Outline: Verification of Login as user 1
Given I login in to app as user
When I give credentials
Then I see the details page
Examples:
|x|y|
|abc|asx|


@test2
Scenario Outline: Verification of testing user
Give I login into app2 as user
When I give credentials
Then I see user name and details application
Examples:
|z|w|
|fdgdfg|gfdg|

Pom configuration:-
<serenity.version>2.1.5</serenity.version>
<serenity.maven.version>2.1.5</serenity.maven.version>
<serenity.cucumber.version>1.9.50</serenity.cucumber.version>
<maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>

Goals:
clean verify -Dcucumber.options="--tags '@test1 or test2'"

Results:
Tests run: 2, failures: 0, Errors: 0, skipped: 0

but Serenity tests result shows as below
SERENITY TESTS: SUCCESS
|Test executed | 1
|Test passed | 1
|Tests with errors | 0
|Tests ignored/skipped | 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified my project and added the feature files, following the Cucumber/Serenity conventions. All the scenarios with Scenario Outline are showing up in the report. Please create the project like  : https://github.com/cliviu/serenity-cucumber5-starter.git.  Please refer to the git issue:- https://github.com/serenity-bdd/serenity-core/issues/2190